# Manipular el tiempo de ejecucion de un fetch

Tags: promesas, fetch

primero que todo disculpa si el titulo no es descriptivo pero la verdad no se que poner...

Les cuento, estoy tratando de entender un poco el flujo del codigo, si bien todos sabemos que el codigo se lee de arriba a abajo a menos que se manipule de cierta manera, mi tema en particular es este.

Tengo una variable que la uso como validador, digamos "validateMessage", el tema es que dependiendo de la respuesta de mi fetch necesito modificar esta variable y asi despues de todo el tema del fetch (es decir, fetch,then,catch) quiero preguntar si esa varibale es true o false para hacer algo, el tema es que no me esta funcionando porque al llegar a mi if aun no esta hecha la promesa y no entiendo como poder manipular esos tiempos a mi antojo

```
let validationMessage = null
console.log("inicio", validationMessage)

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.title) validationMessage = true
            else validationMessage = false
            console.log("dentro", validationMessage) // <-Este es el ultimo en ejecutar
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
    
    console.log("final", validationMessage)
    //La idea es que aquí, ya debería tener el resultdo de la cadena fetch y por ende seguir mi codigo pero me sigue saliendo null
```

Entonces, en que estoy fallando? es necesario poner un setTimeOut para poder seguir avanzando? como puedo tener mas control de lo que quiero hacer?
Ej:
1.-Hacer la llamada
2.- conseguir la info que necesito
3. Dependiendo de la info hacer mi acción final

Muchas gracias!
pd: Entiendo que esta el async await pero quiero poder entender a fondo las promesas antes de pasarme allí y estoy super confundido

Comment: Hola @Programmer89, lamentablemente `console.log("final", validationMessage)` se va a ejecutar siempre primero. Es preferible colocarla en una función que deba ser ejecutada en `.then( data => {} )`.

Comment: Hola! gracias por responder, entonces por ejemplo si tengo un codigo que hace algo despues de conseguir la data, seria necesario ponerlo toooodo en el bloque then y no fuera de la promesa para seguir trabajando?

Comment: Así es, pero preferiblemente, utilizando funciones para evitar tanto código allí.